# Как использовать несколько $index во вложенных ng-repeat для angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Пытаюсь написать небольшое приложение на *angular* для интернет-магазина.

Сейчас в приложении одна директива *ng-repeat* проходит по всем товарам в категории, и когда пользователь нажимает кнопку **купить**, индекс товара - `$index` отсылается в контроллер, и в модели фиксируется факт покупки.

Хочу чтобы в приложении была возможность разбивки товаров на категории с возможностью отсылки в контроллер номера категории и номера товара в категории, но не знаю, возможно ли в *ангуляре* получить оба индекса в разные переменные.

Буду благодарен за Ваши подсказки.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно использовать одновременно индексы вложенных `ng-repeat`. Для этого каждому из них в `ng-init` нужно присвоить алиас.
Например:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-init="categoryIndex=$index">
    <div ng-repeat="product in category.products" ng-init="productIndex=$index">
        category index: {{categoryIndex}}<br/>
        product index: {{productIndex}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на пример в документации для директивы ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#example)

Comment: Проще использовать обращение к внешнему $index через $parent. $parent.$index

Comment: @ДмитрийРодевич, не проще, нужно всегда знать кто является парентом.

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно как у Вас реализованы категории с продуктами, но все действия можно вписать в клик по кнопке **Купить товар**. Например, следующим образом:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products">
        // some product code..
        <button ng-click="addProduct($index, product.id, product.cat.id)">
            Купить продукт
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('productCtrl', [function(){
    $scope.cart = []; //корзина
    $scope.addProduct = function(index, productId, catId) {
        $scope.cart[index] = {'product':productId, 'cat':catId};
    };  
}]);
```

Получить оба индекса в разные переменные возможно также по клику на кнопку (`$scope.productId` и `$scope.productCatId` - переменные из скопа контроллера):

```
// ...
<button ng-click="productId=product.id; productCatId=product.cat.id;">
    Купить продукт
</button>
// ...
```

Детали уже добивайте согласно Вашей реализации.